# Nothing returned from ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, return

I have a simple ajax test set up but it is not returning data. I see this question has been asked many times and I've looked at many of the answers but none helped. My ajax call is

```
    $.ajax({
      type:  'POST',
      data:  dataArray ,
      async: false,
      url: 'add_text_ajax.php',
      dataType: 'text',
      success:function(data) {
         console.log('success '+data);
      }, 
      error: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);       
      }
    });
```

And my ajax file just has

```
    $data = 'yes';
    echo $data;
```

The result display is just "success". Chromes developer tool shows the ajax file is being accessed and the header status for it is 200.

I did try changing the datatype to json and used echo json_encode($data) in the ajax file but it fails with an unexpected end error. Would someone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/7uWHp0i.png  What's the response on the ajax request?

Comment: What do you get when you send a request to your file using a tool like postman?

Comment: Do you send something to your php file? Whats in dataArray? Try to remove dataType, you don't have to use it.

Comment: My thanks to all who replied. It turned out that there was code in the ajax file. It was commented out so I didn't think it mattered but after removing it my posted code worked.

Answer (score -1):

at the beginning of 
`add_text_ajax.php`

you should add
`error_reporting(0);`

this will not print errors and thus can work as expected